# Web Scraping with Selenium : attribute page_souce bugs when too big?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm actually working on a WebScraping project with Python. The goal is to scrape all reviews of an Android app. I'm using Selenium and BeautifulSoup.

Actually I can get approximatly 2300 reviews. Globaly what I do is that I open the webpage of the app with Selenium, then I automated the process of scrolling down the page and clicking on the "show more" button so that I generate more reviews.

Then I passes the "browser.page_source" object to BeautifulSoup method so I can parse it and get the pertinent data. The problem is, from a certain point (after clicking 15 times on show more which correspend to 2320 reviews), the program always stops. I get no message error, but wherever I call the "browser.page_source" object the program stops.

Is the page too big for Selenium to handle ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be difficult to comment on the page size without actually seeing it. Please consider adding more details.

Comment: @Amine, you can add the code to handle the exceptions( if didn't yet)...to know the exact reason...may be it get stopped due to high loading time or something else.